# computation with Hilbert scheme of $n$ points on $\mathbb C^2$

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, hilbert-schemes, symmetric-functions, gauge-theory, string-theory

How can we show that
$$\sum_{n = 0}^\infty q^n \operatorname{char}_T S^n(\mathbb C[x,y])=
\prod_{p_1,p_2\geq 0}\frac{1}{1-t_1^{p_1}t_2^{p_2}q}$$
where $\operatorname{char}_T V$ denotes the character of a representation $V$ of the torus $T$, and $T$ acts on $x,y$ as $(t_1,t_2)$?

References: [proposition 2.1](http://arxiv.org/abs/1210.5181) and [above eq. (4.5)](http://arxiv.org/abs/math/0306198)

Comment: Do you expect us to read these two papers in order to understand the notation?

Comment: @abx does the edit help?

Comment: Can you explain what you tried already? Did you try to write a basis of $S^n(\mathbb{C}[x,y])$ consisting of eigenvectors of the torus, and see what kinds of formulas for characters you get? Did you try to expand the right hand side, and describe the coefficient of $q^n$ there? This question is rather elementary once you unwrap the definitions; Hilbert schemes have nothing to do with that, it is just simple combinatorics / linear algebra.

Comment: @VladimirDotsenko yes, for $n=1$ I get $\frac1{(1-t_1)(1-t_2)}$, while for $n=2$ I'm unable to sum it to $\frac{1+t_1t_2}{(1-t_1)(1-t_2)(1-t_1^2)(1-t_2^2)}$, so rather than computing term by term in $q$ and then resumming, I'd consider it (as suggested in the first reference) a character of $S^*(\mathbb C[x,y])$ with respect to $T\times \mathbb C^*$, where $\mathbb C^*$ acts as $q$: however, I'm not able to see that the result is the one written above, maybe for you it is obvious

Comment: Voting to reopen: I agree that, once the definitions are unwound, this is a question about elementary combinatorics, but I don't think it is an obvious one.

Comment: Sketch of an answer: For each $(\boldsymbol{p}, \boldsymbol{q}) \in (\mathbb{Z}^n)^2$, we get a symmetric function $m_{\boldsymbol{p}, \boldsymbol{q}} = \sum_{\sigma \in S_n} \boldsymbol{x}^{\sigma(\boldsymbol{p})} \boldsymbol{y}^{\sigma(\boldsymbol{q})}$. Here bolded symbols denote vectors with $n$ entries, and $\boldsymbol{x}^{\boldsymbol{p}} = x_1^{p_1} \cdots x_n^{p_n}$. As $(\boldsymbol{p}, \boldsymbol{q})$ ranges over $(\mathbb{Z}^n)^2/S_n$, we get a basis of $S^n \mathbb{C}[x,y]$. The basis element $m_{\boldsymbol{p}, \boldsymbol{q}}$ has torus weight $t^{\sum p_i} u^{\sum q_i}$.

Comment: What remain is to notice that $\sum_n \sum_{(\boldsymbol{p}, \boldsymbol{q}) \in (\mathbb{Z}^n)^2/S_n} z^n t^{\sum p_i} u^{\sum q_i} = \prod \frac{1}{1-z t^{p} u^{q}}$.

Comment: @DavidSpeyer Thanks. Could you please explain how you get this last equality?

Comment: $\frac{1}{1-z t^p u^q} = \sum_{m=0}^{\infty} z^m t^{pm} u^{qm}$. Now multiply out the product.

Comment: @DavidSpeyer: what I mean is that $S^\bullet(V\oplus W)\simeq S^\bullet(V)\otimes S^\bullet(W)$, so the generating function for characters of symmetric powers of $\mathbb{C}[x,y]$ is the product of generating functions of characters of symmetric powers of one-dimensional representations into which it splits, - which is exactly what this formula says.

Comment: @VladimirDotsenko That's a better explanation, thanks.